# Differences between "Full control" and "Contribute" Permission

Tags: 2013, permissions

I'm kinda confused on the SharePoint 2013 permission levels.

I found this [MS Technet Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx) describing the permission levels, but I cannot figure out how to distinguish the difference of the **full control** level and the **contribute** level especially on folders and lists.

- Are there any differences on this specific items?
- Is the contribute level entitled to manage permissions for this folder/list as well or do the user need full control to be able to manage them?

regards

Answer (score 2):

I don't need to give you academic definition but you should follow the mentioned steps below to check the difference between **all permissions level types** not only Full control and Contribute

- Go to site settings > users and permissions > site permissions.

[image]

- From the above ribbon select permission levels

[image]

- You can check the difference between **all permissions level types** not only Full control and Contribute

[image]

- Click on Full control and Contribute to know specifically what's the difference based on SharePoint Settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Full Control** permission level:

> Contains all available SharePoint permissions. By default, this permission level is assigned to the Owners group. It can’t be customized or deleted.

**Contribute** permission level:

> View, add, update, and delete list items and documents.

[Reference](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)

Answer (score 0):

In case of managing specific items I think both full control and Contribute has same permissions.

> Contribute permission level does not have rights to Manage list so you
>   can't use it to manage permission or list setting for the list or
>   library.
>
> To manage permission for folder or list you can use Full control or
>   Edit permission level

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage permissions for a folder or list, the *Manage Permissions* capability is required. There are only two permission levels that have this capability by default: *Full Control, Manage Hierarchy*

you can check the settings here at https://yourdomain/_layouts/15/role.aspx